# jaxrs-2.0 service is throwing class cast exception in Liberty 8.5.5.6

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I need a Rest service which has to receive binary data (pdf file) 
from a client. I have simple Rest service as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response upload(@FormParam("body") String filename,
        @FormParam("attachment") InputStream is) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("filename: " + filename);
    System.out.println("filelength: " + is.available());

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

when I invoke this service from a java client, I get following exception.

[ERROR ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in application [RecieveFileApp]: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:322)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to interface org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory

Thanks
Madhu

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860075/jax-rs-fileupload-with-apache-cxf

Comment: When I follow the steps provided above (which is for TomEE), I get the following error in the server.  No message body reader has been found for class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary="uuid:150c3ab5-5e1a-4997-9c5d-c9eef6ebb8af"